# How to force a merge with an ancestor?

Tags: mercurial

I branched off changeset "A". Later, "A" was merged into default. Then it was decided that "A" was not ready to go live, so someone `hg revert -a`'d it to an older revision and pushed that. Now I'm trying to merge default into my branch, but because those changes were reverted, they're all being ripped out of my branch.

I want to force a re-merge with "A" so that I can get all those changes back. How can I do that?

**Update:** I just tried backing out the changeset that undoing "A" was made on. It looks like this gave me all my code changes back.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you solved your problem already.  I was going to point you to http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html and then mention that you try to "hg revert" the commit that previously reverted the changes you want back.

Comment: Doesn't "revert" revert all the changes made all the way back to that changeset, not just the changeset itself? Whereas backout just undoes the one changeset?

Comment: @Mark: That sounds right, but it's hard to see the complete scenario from just the text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to re-merge "A" you can backout the changeset where "A" was undone on default. e.g.,

```
hg backout -r <changeset>
```