# How to Merge files from previous revision number to tip in mercurial?

Tags: merge, mercurial, tortoisehg, dvcs

Suppose I have a revision "6443" however this revision does not have changes which were committed with revision number "6409".

Here to get the changes from "6409" merged with revision "6443" I am thinking of a solution one is get the files from "6409" merge with "6443" and Commit however it would go with new revision number i.e 6444 which I dont want.

***Please note here i am trying to merge in the same branch***

Is there any other way where I can achieve the same?

Thanks

[image: Graph- Mercurial]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DAG you attached shows that a merge is not necessary, as changeset 6409 is a direct descendent of your tip changeset 6443. Thus if the changes of 6409 are not present anymore, there is some intermediate changeset which undoes what 6409 introduced. The right course of action would be to `revert` or `backout` that commit which damages the desired changes of changeset 6409.

See also http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html

This question also basically is a duplicate of
[How to force a merge with an ancestor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282199/how-to-force-a-merge-with-an-ancestor)